# How to add jdbc driver for accessing Ingres database in Grails

Tags: grails, jdbc, grails-orm, ingres

I'm trying to access an Ingres Database via Hibernate/GORM in my Grails app. I'm failing at the point integrating the correct jdbc driver.

How do I add the jdbc driver for ingres databases?

Answer (score 0):

In `BuildConfig.groovy` add dependency:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    dependencies {
        runtime 'com.ingres.jdbc:iijdbc:10.0-4.0.6'
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Then refresh dependencies:

```
grails refresh-dependencies
```

Tell GORM/Hibernate to use the driver in `datasources`:

```
dataSource {
    driverClassName = "com.ingres.jdbc.IngresDriver"
    url = "jdbc:ingres://...."
    ...
}
```

Usefull JDBC driver Informations [here](http://community.actian.com/wiki/Ingres_Java_Development_Center/Ingres_Java_Learn).

Available JDBC driver versions via Maven [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ingres.jdbc/iijdbc).